# How to override component's style?

Tags: react-native

Hi i'm new to React Native. I created a Button component for using it everywhere. I just want to change style values on every screen. How can i override it?

These are my codes:

Component:

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.onButtonPressed}
            >
                <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.children}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

Component Style:

```
button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: "rgba(65, 99, 12, 0.7)",
    zIndex: 100,
}
```

Login screen:

```
                <Button style={styles.button || styles.registerButton}>
                    <Text>Register</Text>
                </Button>
```

Login Style:

```
registerButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(65, 87, 159, 0.7)',
    width: 140,
    height: 28,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure your button inherits `View.propTypes`.

```
// Button component
Button.propTypes = {
    ... // Your other props
    ...View.propTypes
}

<View style={styles.container}>
    <TouchableOpacity
         style={[styles.button, this.props.style]}
         onPress={this.onButtonPressed}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.children}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Then you can pass multiple styles as an array like so:

```
// Login
<Button style={styles.registerButton}>
    ...
</Button>
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much.